# Do I need Mathematica use System Modeler?

Tags: system-modeler

I found a couple of interesting model examples that I would like to run in System Modeler.

https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/examples/life-sciences/insulin-receptor-signaling.html

Do I need to also install Mathematica to work with System Modeler or can it has work without Mathematica being installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[System modeler](https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/) uses the modelica language for its processing and does *not* require mathematica. You can test this by downloading the trial. But like mentioned you won’t have any issues

[System requirements](https://wolfram.com/system-modeler/system-requirements.html)

[Trial download](https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/trial/)

But keep in mind there are valuable interconnections between the two softwares and Mathematica is a powerful and useful tool to learn.